# Select all rows within a date range, with at least one row occurring in the last given month

Tags: sql-server

I've run out of ideas for this one and I'm not sure how to do this whatsoever.
I'll give you my current query that gives me the rows I need for the date range;

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT FER.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FER.Report_Subject, FER.Event_Category) AS Event_Count
FROM FacilityEventReport FER INNER JOIN
FacilityEventReport_RMReview RMR ON FER.ID = RMR.FER_ID
WHERE RMR.Review_Status = 'Active' AND FER.Report_About = 'Resident' AND @BeginDate <= FER.Event_Date AND @EndDate >= FER.Event_Date AND (LEN(ISNULL(@Category,'')) = 0) OR @Category = FER.Event_Category)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Event_Count > 1
ORDER BY Report_Subject
```

The above query returns all events that have occurred within the date parameters @BeginDate and @EndDate. @Category is an optional parameter, only used to filter the query by Event_Category. This query returns all of the requested rows, but I need at least ONE of the rows returned to be in the MONTH of the second date parameter (@EndDate).

This query is used for a report.

The parameters @BeginDate and @EndDate are both of the type DateTime. As is the field Event_Date.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Kramb

**CLARIFICATION:**

Condensed Data:

```
  Event_Date  |  Report_Subject  |  Event_Category
----------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
2016-01-02    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
2016-02-01    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
2016-01-01    |  Patient 2       |  Fall
2016-01-02    |  Patient 2       |  Fall
2016-03-01    |  Patient 3       |  Fall
```

If I run the query with the following parameters:

```
@BeginDate = '2016-01-01';
@EndDate   = '2016-02-01';
```

I want the following data returned:

```
  Event_Date  |  Report_Subject  |  Event_Category
----------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
2016-01-02    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
2016-02-01    |  Patient 1       |  Aggressive Act
```

Notice that Patient 1 was returned because they had more than one event of the same type. Also, An event occurred within the month of the second parameter.

Patient 2 did have more than one event, but because those events did not occur in the month of the second parameter the rows were not returned.

Comment: Are you saying you need a row to be returned for the month of the EndDate even if there is no such row in your database?

Comment: No, the results are grouped by the report subject and the event category. If the report subject has more than one event category within a range of dates, then the query returns all of those rows. I need one of those returned rows to be within the month of the second date parameter (@EndDate). If none of the events are within the second month, no rows should be returned for that report subject.

Comment: I cannot picture what you are describing.   Can you add sample data, current results, and desired results?

Comment: Sure, not a problem. Give me one minute to set it up.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that if a patient doesn't have one of their rows in the last month, then you don't want ANY rows returned for that patient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways.   One is to add this to the end of your current query:

```
...
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE t2 WHERE t2.Report_Subject=CTE.Report_Subject
  AND DATEDIFF(Month, Event_Date, @EndDate)=0
)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, my mind has gone to mush. Luckily this was the last report query out of about 20.

Comment: Spoke too soon, I'm still getting results that aren't in the month of the @EndDate parameter.

Comment: Can you give an example of a result you're getting that you shouldn't?   Are you accounting for whether those rows are eliminated by the JOIN in your CTE?

Comment: It's not the JOIN. The EXISTS is eliminating rows. Basically I need the result set as a group because I still need to return ALL of the rows from the CTE if one of the rows from the CTE match the EndDate

Comment: EXISTS would not eliminate those rows.  I would have to see an example of what you are seeing.

Comment: I'm creating a SQLFiddle right now to maybe clear this up.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it. Just needed to add one more condition to the WHERE clause in the EXISTS. The category had to be the same as well.